# Creating PDF file of the screen/browser content output in PHp

Tags: javascript, pdf, screenshot

I am working with google maps where i am creating route using marker. Now i onclick on some button(Javascript), i need to save the screen shot in pdf format to some directory.

I have searched across the web, but could not find any satisfiable solution.